# How can I use HTML and CSS to create a slanted Navigation bar Design?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a navigation menu with slanted shapes as shown in the photo below. Can someone give me any input on the best way to go about creating this when my navigation bar links are  tags?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here's my current navigation bar:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #637BAD;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #637BAD;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10"><div class="topnav" id="navigation" style="margin-top: -2%;">
      <a class="active" href="MusicFestival.php">Home <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      <a style="background-color: blueviolet" href="Friday.php">Friday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
      <a style="background-color: steelblue"href="Saturday.php">Saturday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>
        <a style="background-color: lightblue"href="Sunday.php">Sunday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>  
  </div></div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code written so far?

Comment: All I have is my Navigation bar

Comment: For future reference: Insert the graphic and not link to it. Some of us work places where file sharing sites are blocked.

Comment: Noted, my apologies.

Comment: @Elijah The user does not have enough reputation to be able to embed images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/uzts3omw/

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font: normal 18px/100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a {
    background: #005771;
    color: #005771;
}

.nav li:nth-child(2) a {
    background: #710000;
    color: #710000;
}

.nav li:nth-child(3) a {
    background: #147100;
    color: #147100;
}

.nav li:nth-child(4) a {
    background: #716a00;
    color: #716a00;
}

.nav li a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border: 20px solid;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background: #0040ff;
}

.nav li a:hover::before, .nav li a:hover::after {
  border-color: #0040ff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect, only problem is that my text appears in squares which go over the border of the shapes?

Comment: Can you provide an image of it?

Comment: Nevermind, I had some other CSS which was getting in the way of it. Fixed now - thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HRWqq/

CSS :

```css
li{
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
li > a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 20px solid #ccc;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
li > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 20px solid #ccc;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}





li:first-child > a {
    background: #aaa;
}
li:first-child > a:after {
    border-top-color: #aaa;
    border-left-color: #aaa;
}

li:last-child > a {
    background: #ddd;
}
li:last-child > a:before{
    border-right-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
}
li:last-child > a:after {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
HTML :

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, it works :) How can I style this so that each of them are a different colour?

Comment: Insert this html and check                                                                              
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><font color="red">This is some text!</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><font color="blue">This is some text!</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><font color="yellow">This is some text!</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><font color="green">This is some text!</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><font color="dark">This is some text!</font></a></li>
</ul>

Comment: No i mean how can I change the background colour of each li?

Comment: Add this in html   :  <li><a class="active" href="#h">Home</a></li>                                                                
                                                                                                                            
and this in css :  <li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. I only did one.

```css
#home{
  margin-top: -2%; 
  padding:20px; 
  background:linear-gradient(300deg, transparent 30px, #777 30px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="topnav" id="navigation" style="margin-top: -2%;">
      <a id="home" class="active" href="MusicFestival.php">Home
        <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
      </a>
      <a style="background-color: blueviolet" href="Friday.php">Friday 
        <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
      </a>
      <a style="background-color: steelblue"href="Saturday.php">Saturday 
        <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
      </a>
        <a style="background-color: lightblue"href="Sunday.php">Sunday 
          <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
          </a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I edit this so that the Friday page doesn't have a straight line on the left side of it? So that it continues like in the image I originally uploaded?